# testing for empty multi-select lists

Tags: php, listbox, multi-select

multi-select lists are named thusly: `<select name="list[]" multiple>`

When the form is submitted, if the user hasn't selected anything, then I wish to ignore that input.
I'm trying:

```
if (isset($_POST["list"]))
```

and

```
if (count($_POST["list"]))
```

but that throws an error, presumably because PHP doesn't receive the array unless at least one item is selected.  If the user does select at least one of the options, there is no error.

The complaint is that "list" is a nonexistent index.

I need at least one of these solutions:
To force the submit to send an empty array so the index in `$_POST` will be legal, OR
I need to test for the existence of the index variable without throwing an error.

I'm also trying to use the `try-catch` syntax but having issues with that as well.  I have a separate post open for that issue.

any suggestions on detecting a listbox with nothing selected?

Thanks,
Dana

Comment: did you read the feedbcak on your last question?

Comment: `if (isset($_POST["list"]))` should be always used before any calling to `$_POST['list']`. If index doesn't exist, `isset` return false without any errors.

Answer (score 3):

Try using [`empty()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php):

```
if (!empty($_POST["list"])) {
```

For your case, `!empty()` would be `TRUE` if `list[]` is set **and** if it has at least one value.

**From the documentation:**

Returns `FALSE` if var exists and has a non-empty, non-zero value. Otherwise returns `TRUE`.

The following things are considered to be empty:

- `""` (an empty string)
- `0` (`0` as an integer)
- `0.0` (`0` as a float)
- `"0"` (`0` as a string)
- `NULL`
- `FALSE`
- `array()` (an empty array)
- `$var;` (a variable declared, but without a value)

Comment: @Dana White - If this answers your question, be sure mark it as answered so other people who run across this issue can use it, too.

Comment: now I don't understand.  It's working perfectly.  Both isset() AND empty() are no longer throwing errors.

Comment: okay, just to make me look completely stupid -- you asked that I mark this question as 'answered.'  BUT, I don't see any buttons or 'answered' indicators.

Comment: @DanaWhite - There's an outline of a checkbox just below the votes for this post. Click the checkbox and it is marked as answered. For more information, check out [What should I do when someone answers my question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).